# How to split columns using selectInput

Tags: r, shiny

After collecting the column input from the user using R shiny, I want to unmerge the column "Type."

I have a separate code for unmerging (unmerge.R) the columns, and I'd like to use it as a source code in R shiny so that whenever the user uploads the csv, clicking the "Unmerge" button will unmerge the columns and display the result on the Main panel.

Note: I've stated the dataframe for the sake of clarity, but it's actually a csv file that the user submits to Shiny.

Since I am new to R shiny, Could someone help me to accomplish this.?

**unmerge.R**:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

library(svDialogs)
column_name <- dlg_input("Enter a number", Sys.info()["user"])$res

before_merge<- data.frame(ID=21:23, Type=c('A1 B1', 'C1 D1', 'E1 F1'))
before_merge

library(reshape2)

newColNames <- c("Unmerged_type1", "Unmerged_type2")
#column_name <- readline(prompt="Enter the desired column name: ")
newCols <- colsplit(before[[column_name]], " ", newColNames)
after_merge <- cbind(before, newCols)
after[[column_name]] <- NULL
```

**app.R**

```
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
library(shiny)
if (interactive()) {
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
        checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
        actionButton("dataset2", "Unmerge", class = "btn-primary"),
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("contents")
      )
    )
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$contents <- renderTable({
      file <- input$file1
      ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
      
      req(file)
      validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
      
      read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header)
    })
    observeEvent(input$dataset2, {
      source("test.R", local = TRUE)
    })
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to define the logic from `unmerge.R` as a function and call it inside the R server

```r
## unmerge.R
unmerge <- function(before_merge, column_name) {
  newColNames <- c("Unmerged_type1", "Unmerged_type2")
  newCols <- reshape2::colsplit(before_merge[[column_name]], " ", newColNames)
  after_merge <- cbind(before_merge, newCols)
  after_merge[[column_name]] <- NULL
  after_merge
}
```

```r
## app.R
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
source("unmerge.R")

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    input$file1 %>%
      req() %$% 
      datapath %>%
      read.csv(header = input$header) %>%
      unmerge(input$column_name)
  })
}

## ...
```

Comment: I am receiving the error as : `> server <- function(input, output, session) {
+   output$contents <- renderTable({
+     input$file1 %>%
+       req() %$% 
+       datapath %>%
+    .... [TRUNCATED]`

Comment: while checking, I used the same UI code as I specified in the Initial post.